# google - Auth0.js Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call

Tags: auth0, authorize, cross-origin-opener-policy, window.closed

I am creating OwnUI with Auth0.js and getting below error on webAuth.popup.authorize(
winchan.js:150 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
winchan.js:195 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call.

Please help on this issue

webAuth.popup.authorize({

responseType: ‘token’,

connection: ‘google-oauth2’,

redirect_uri: ‘https://localhost:44335/createaccount.aspx’,

prompt: ‘login’,

owp: true,

scope: “profile email openid”,

}, (err, authResult) => {

```
            if (err != null) {

                console.log(err);
                return false;

            }

            webAuth.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, function (err, user) {


                if (err != null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (user != null) {

                    //doing something

                }
            });
           
        });
```

Need remove these javascript errors